# Regex to trim hyphens from start and end of a string

Tags: regex

What's a regex pattern to trim the hyphens from the start and end of a string?

```
-----name1-name2-----
```

should become

```
name1-name2
```

`^(-+).+(-+)$` doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the opposite approach, and pull the middle out like this:

```
^-+(.+?)-+$
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match either the beginning or the end like this:

```
(^-+)|(-+$)
```

If I try this out in PowerShell I get the following result:

```
PS> "-----name1-name2----" -replace "(^-+)|(-+$)", ""
name1-name2
```