# How to write regular expression to match only numbers, letters and dashes?

Tags: regex, validation, url, slug

I need an expression that will only accept:

- numbers
- normal letters (no special characters)
- -

Spaces are not allowed either.

Example:
The regular expression should match:
`this-is-quite-alright`

It should not match
`this -is/not,soålright`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-]*$
```

This matches strings, possibly empty, that is wholly composed of uppercase/lowercase letters (ASCII A-Z), digits (ASCII 0-9), and a dash.

This matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/EHQypXPHWH)):

```
this-is-quite-alright
and-a-1-and-a-2-and-3-4-5

yep---------this-is-also-okay
```

And rejects:

```
this -is/not,soålright
hello world
```

Explanation:

- `^` and `$` are beginning and end of string anchors respectively

  - If you're looking for matches within a string, then you don't need the anchors
- `[...]` is a character class

  - `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` in a character class define ranges
  - `-` as a last character in a class is a literal dash
- `*` is zero-or-more repetition

#### regular-expressions.info

- [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

---

#### Variation

The specification was not clear, but if `-` is only to be used to separate "words", i.e. no double dash, no trailing dash, no preceding dash, then the pattern is more complex (only slightly!)

```
  _"alpha"_    separating dash
 /         \  /
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
 \__________/| \__________/|\
    "word"   |    "word"   | zero-or-more
             \_____________/
              group together
```

This matches strings that is at least one "word", where words consists of one or more "alpha", where "alpha" consists of letters and numbers. More "words" can follow, and they're always separated by a dash.

This matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/XegwcRTAF8)):

```
this-is-quite-alright
and-a-1-and-a-2-and-3-4-5
```

And rejects:

```
--no-way
no-way--
no--way
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
I went with this and it works like a charm :)

Comment: The last thing.. Can you make it reject -- as well?

Comment: Works perfect :)
If anybody is wondering, it is used to validate a SEO optimized slug for an URL. like
www.mydomain.com/57/{slug}.aspx

Comment: @polygenelubricants: As always, great detailed answer +1 :)

Comment: @sAc: for what it's worth, I'm sure this is a dupe. It's just faster to answer it than to look for the dupe.

Comment: @Brinth: if you look around, there are many questions about URL slugging, both matching and transforming. That is, there is already a question (or ten!) about transforming `"Hey! How are you, buddy!"` to `hey-how-are-you-buddy`, which I'm sure is sufficiently answered. Just look around. Actually, let me just do that also and I'll update this answer with links to those questions. For now, look at the community wiki answer.

Comment: Okay I didn't search for the slugging questions however I don't need to transform anything.. I need it to be well thought of and no nessecarily the same as the title. The title could easily contain words like "and,or,if,which". All words that I don't need in my url for the specific SEO project. But thanks for all thorough walkthrough of everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-z0-9-]+
```

But your question is confusing as it asks for letters and numbers and has an example containing a dash.

Comment: You are missing the capitals `A-Z`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected/ -- see A-Z examples. `A-z` is legal, but includes 6 additional non-letter characters.

Comment: @polygenelubricans Didn't know that, it would make sense if it also matched the ASCII characters between Z and a

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki, an attempt to compile links to related questions about this "URL/SEO slugging" topic. Community is invited to contribute.

#### Related questions

- [regex/php: how can I convert 2+ dashes to singles and remove all dashes at the beginning and end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741553/regex-php-how-can-i-convert-2-dashes-to-singles-and-remove-all-dashes-at-the-be)

  - `-this--is---a-test--` becomes `this-is-a-test`
- [Regex for [a-zA-Z0-9-] with dashes allowed in between but not at the start or end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525327/regex-for-a-za-z0-9-with-dashes-allowed-in-between-but-not-at-the-start-or-e)

  - allow `spam123-spam-eggs-eggs1` reject `eggs1-`, `-spam123`, `spam--spam`
- [Translate “Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet” into SEO friendly “Lorem-3-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658991/how-to-translate-lorem-3-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-into-seo-friendly-lorem-3-ipsum)

#### Related tags

- [`[slug]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slug)